# Writing content of one file to another using replace mulin powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have two text file which contains following

file1.txt

```
Abcd
Efgh
HIJK
```

sample.txt

```
Some pre content goes here


File1Content
```

Now what i am trying to do is read all content from file1.txt and use sample.txt and replace File1Content word with actual content of the file1.txt but it is providing output in single line.

output.txt should look like this

```
Some pre content goes here
Abcd
Efgh
HIJK
```

But it is currently looking like this

```
Some pre content goes here
Abcd  Efgh    HIJK
```

I am using following code which works , i tried adding  r and n but it doesnt work. Could someone please help

```
$filecontent = Get-Content "C:\location\file1.txt"
(Get-Content -path C:\Location\sample.txt -Raw)   ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "File1Content", "$filecontent`r`n" } | Set-Content C:\Export\output.txt
```

Comment: `-Raw` reads the whole file as a single string instead of an array of strings (lines, basically). That's the reason why this happens - the NewLine-suggestion in Martins answer might solve the problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the NewLine to each entry in `$filecontent`. You could do this using the `-join` operator:

```
$_ -replace "File1Content", "$($filecontent -join [Environment]::NewLine)"
```

Answer (score 1):

And foreach loop can be deleted

```
$filecontent = Get-Content "d:\testdir\file1.txt"
(Get-Content -path "d:\testdir\sample.txt").Replace("File1Content","$($filecontent -join [Environment]::NewLine)")| Set-Content d:\testdir\output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-Raw` parameter is greatly used to boost Get-Content speed. It reads the whole file as a single string skipping the newlines. So the reading is fast. You can try this:

```
$newcontent = Get-Content "sample.txt" | Foreach { 
  $_ -replace "File1Content", "$(Get-Content file1.txt)"
}
$newcontent | Set-Content output.txt
```